# Connecting two TextFields so that entering values in one TextField causes to change the value of other one

Tags: ios, iphone

I am developing a converter app. In iOS, we don't have anything like drop down. For one or two conversions its not a problem. But for multiple conversions of same type(like for time:years to months,days,hours,minutes and seconds) we have opposite conversions also. It makes UIView look bad. 
But connecting two TextFields solves half of the problem for opposite conversion of same type. I don't know how to connect them so that interaction of user with one textfield changes automatically the value of other one. How to achieve this?

Comment: Who said there is no drop down in iOS ? There are many ways of achieving it.

Comment: You can use KVO. Add observer to a textfield and apply the changes to the other text field. I haven't test it or try it but it should work.

Comment: your question is not clear. what is your problem exactly? Try to add a screenshot of this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be proper way to do it

```
[_textField addTarget:self action:@selector(handleChanging:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string  
{
    if (textField == txtField1)
    {
       //Put your conversion , every character enter in textBox one will effect the textFiled2
     textField2.text = //put your conversion output
    return YES;
    }

}
```

Try like this